# Username and password appearing in the URL

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have a login page like this:

```
<body>  
    <form action="/my_app/homepage" method="get" class="navbar-form pull-left">
    <input name="username" type="text" class="span2">
     <input name="password" type="password" class="span2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

When I click on the `Submit` button it takes me to the `/my_app/homepage` but at the same time it also displays the username and password in the addressbar.

Am I doing it the wrong way? How can I avoid displaying the username & password?

Comment: Go read up on what the difference between HTTP methods GET and POST is …

Comment: You shouldnt have to build your own forms with ruby on rails. This html specifically has nothing to do with rails.

Comment: @CBroe: I tried using POST, but it throws me error.

Comment: Well then the part where you’re _processing_ the send data might need adapting to that as well.

Comment: @Sparkplug post the error details here and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Ritikesh: Routing error

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
This is very informative and helpful. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the Http Request method of FORM is `GET`. Which would always show the form data in the URL. To hide the data of the form, you need to use `POST` request.

Change the code to the following:

```
<form action="/my_app/homepage" method="post" class="navbar-form pull-left">
  <input name="username" type="text" class="span2">
  <input name="password" type="password" class="span2">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Check the `method="post"` and you'll get the URL only without any sort of Query String.

Comment: The form is explicitly GET, so it isn't a question of defaults.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: but when I change it to `method="post"`, it throws me Routing error.

Answer (score 2):

The `GET` method will append the form variables to the URL, using the `POST` method. From W3Schools:

"POST is a little safer than GET because the parameters are not stored in browser history or in web server logs." Also "Data is not displayed in the URL".

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: this is the correct answer to the above question.

Comment: Also consider encoding the credentials before sending it to the backend server.